# An example of short exact sequence which is not exact triangle.

Tags: homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

Let $0 \to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \to 0$ be a short exact sequence of complexes concentrated in degree $0$. How can I prove that it cannot be made into an exact trianle?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738348/a-short-exact-sequence-that-cannot-be-made-into-an-exact-triangle-weibel-10-1